# Promises.all() acts wierd in Edge and Safari

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I'm trying to call multiple functions, which all returns a promise, on a button click. When all of these are done, something should happen (this case simply a `location.reload()`).

My code works fine in Chrome, however in Safari and MS Edge, it will add all functions to the `promises` array, and then reload before they're done.

**This is my code**

```
  button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.classList.add('disabled');
    let promises = [];
    let total_qty = 0;

    for (var variant of registrered_variants) {
      promises.push(
        FunctionThatReturnsAPromise();
      )
      total_qty += variant.qty
    }

    // reload page when all functions ran.
    Promise.all(promises).then(() => location.reload());
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The promise chain actually worked as supposed. The problem was in my `FunctionThatReturnsAPromise()` function..